# JPanel Positioning using the Border Layout not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, border-layout

I am trying to setup my `JPanel`'s position to the right using `i.add(jp, BorderLayout.EAST);` but it is not working. Any ideas why? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
/* INSTANCE DECLARATIONS */
private JTextField tf;//text field instance variable
private JLabel jl2;//label instance variable


/*****************
 * WINDOW METHOD *
 * ***************/
public void window() {

    LoadImageApp i = new LoadImageApp();//calling image class

    JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();//declaration
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter a Letter:");//prompt with label

    tf = new JTextField(1);//length of text field by character
    jl2 = new JLabel("Letters Used:    ");

    jp.add(jl);//add label to panel
    jp.add(tf);//add text field to panel
    jp.add(jl2);//add letters used

    gameFrame.add(i); //adds background image to window
    i.add(jp, BorderLayout.EAST); // adds panel containing label to background image panel

    gameFrame.setTitle("Hangman");//title of frame window
    gameFrame.setSize(850, 600);//sets size of frame
    gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//exit when 'x' button pressed
    gameFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("Hangman-Game-grey.png").getImage());//set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file
    gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//window centered
    gameFrame.setResizable(false);//user can not resize window
    gameFrame.setVisible(true);//display frame


 }//end window method
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What layout manager does `i`, your `LoadImageApp` instance, use? I'm betting it's not `BorderLayout`. I'm betting that the `LoadImageApp` class extends `JPanel` and if so and if you never explicitly set its layout, then it uses a `FlowLayout` by default, and as you're finding out, `FlowLayout` doesn't respect the `BorderLayout.EAST` int constant.

The solution is likely quite simple: make it use a `BorderLayout`:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> When I set the border layout of i to EAST, my background image shifts to the right also, is there a way to get around that?

No, you're missing the point. You need to set the layout of LoadImageApp to BorderLayout. You're not supposed to add i BorderLayout.EAST. This was never recommended to you.

i.e.,

```
public class LoadImageApp extends JPanel {

  // in the constructor
  public LoadImageApp() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  }

  // .... etc....
}
```

THe LoadImageApp instance (which I would name loadImageApp, not `i`), should be added BorderLayout.CENTER, which you were doing before. Please read the layout manager tutorials which you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: When I set the border layout of i to EAST, my background image shifts to the right also, is there a way to get around that?